# Unexpected out with Dynamic Binding

Tags: java

What is the reason for the output we are getting?

As per me, with `b.getx()` we will get the reference id of an object of B and `b.getx().x` should get the value of 10. But when I run this program, the output is 5. Why?

```
class Base {
  int x = 5;
  public Base getx() {
    return new Base();
  }
}

class Child extends Base {
  int x = 10;
  public Child getx() {
    return new Child();
  }

  public static void main(String ...s) {
    Base b = new Child();
    System.out.println(b.getx().x);
  }
}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.11.1

Answer (score 8):

Field accesses (unlike method calls) are not subject to runtime dynamic dispatch, they're resolved purely based on compile-time types.

The variable `b` is of compile-time type `Base`, therefore `b.getx()` is also of compile-time type `Base`, and so `b.getx().x` will be compiled into an access of Base's `x` field, not Child's.  This is confirmed by looking at the output of `javap` for the `main` method:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0:   new #3; //class Child
   3:   dup
   4:   invokespecial   #4; //Method "<init>":()V
   7:   astore_1
   8:   getstatic   #5; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   11:  aload_1
   12:  invokevirtual   #6; //Method Base.getx:()LBase;
   15:  getfield    #7; //Field Base.x:I
   18:  invokevirtual   #8; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
   21:  return
```

you can see that `b.getx().x` was compiled into a `getfield` instruction for `Base.x` specifically.

Comment: Does that mean data members get binded at compile time ? Because if we remove int x from both classes and go with System.out.println(b.getx()); it calls the child class object.

Comment: @ShardaPrasadJaiswal yes, the _runtime_ type of `b.getx()` will be `Child` but that doesn't affect field accesses `a.x` which are based only on the _compile-time_ type of the expression to the left of the dot.  Imagine if `Base.x` and `Child.x` were of different types (e.g. one `int` and one `String`)...

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic binding basically means that the method implementation that is actually called is determined at run-time, and not at compile-time. And that’s why it’s called dynamic binding – because the method that will be run is chosen at run time. Dynamic binding is also known as late binding.

Answer (score 1):

`Base b = new Child();` is resolve at run-time and by rules of dynamic binding(run-time polymorphism) all method related to that should bind at run-time so...

```
public Base getx() {
    return new Base();
  }
```

that lines return new instance of base class and you just called variable on that instance.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic Binding is runtime time process for looking the declaration at run time. It is also known as late binding in which a call to an overridden method is resolved at runtime rather than compile-time.
In an object-oriented system method overriding (dynamic Polymorphism) is done at run time. When overriding one method with another, the signatures of the two methods must be identical.

**Example:**

```
class Animal{

  public void eat(){
      System.out.println("Animals voice");
   }

public void go(){
      System.out.println("Animals can walk");
   }

}

class Dog extends Animal{

   public void go(){
      System.out.println("Dogs can walk and run");
   }
   public void eat(){
      System.out.println("Dogs can eat a wide range of foods");
   }
}
```